# How to add event to ListView.ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, binding, listviewitem

I would like to have ListViewItem with data from binding and with 2 events.

My code:

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
    <Grid Name="MailListViewItem">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" FontWeight="Bold"  Text="{Binding Topic}"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="8" Foreground="Blue" Text="{Binding Time}"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Foreground="Gray" Text="{Binding Text}"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Where should I put `MouseDoubleClick="Mail_DoubleClick" MouseLeftButtonUp="Mail_MouseLeftButtonUp"`?

Comment: What is stopping you from [using Commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern#relaying-command-logic) instead of Event handlers? BTW, you may add Event handlers to `Grid` in the template with adding `Background="Transparent"` there, it will allow `Grid` to catch the click at empty space.

Answer (score 1):

You could define an `ItemContainerStyle` with `EventSetters`:

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <EventSetter Event="MouseLeftButtonUp" Handler="Mail_DoubleClick" />
            <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="Mail_MouseLeftButtonUp" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    ...
```

Or you could handle the events of the `Grid` in the `DataTemplate` provided that you set its `Background` property to some brush:

```
 <Grid Name="MailListViewItem" Background="Transparent" MouseLeftButtonDown="...">
```

If you handle `MouseLeftButtonDown`, there is a `ClickCount` property of the `MouseButtonEventArgs` that you can check to determine whether the element as double clicked:

```
private void MailListViewItem_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ClickCount == 2)
    {
        //doule click
    }
    else
    {
        //click...
    }
}
```